# how to get only length of table? And also check whether the each row cell or column consists of INCOMPLETE word? with number of INCOMPLETE word?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("records");
console.log("reading?");
for ( i = 0; length = table1.rows.length; i++) 
{       
console.log('Hi');
console.log(length);
console.log('bye');
/*for (var j = 0; cell = table1.cells[j]; j++) 
{
if(cell.toUpperCase().trim()=="INCOMPLETE")
{
console.log(length+cell);
}
}*/
```

Here I am trying to find out the length of the row, where I want to assign it and store it inside a variable. Also I want to loop inside, check the columns which have 'INCOMPLETE' word and take the number of that row. Finally I should have total number of rows and number of rows having 'INCOMPLETE' word.

What I am getting is on table1.rows.length is infinite loop, since it has no condition in it. If I put table1.rows[i] I would get number of  shown than showing up how many      number of  exists.

Comment: You loop-condition in your `for` loop is buggy and hence the infinite loop. Change it to something like: `for ( i = 0; i < table1.rows.length; i++) `

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( i = 0; length = table1.rows.length; i++) 
                    ^
                    here
```

You have it as infinite loop because, you are using second part of for loop with assignment statement.

It should be like

```
for( i=0, length=table1.rows.length; i<length; i++)
```

---

So, this one might be what you want

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("records");
var length = table1.rows.length;
var r = [];
var count = 0;
for ( i = 0; i<length; i++) 
{
    for (var j = 0; j < table1.rows[i].cells.length; j++) 
    {
        cell = table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
        if(cell.toUpperCase().trim()=="INCOMPLETE")
        {
            r[count] = i;
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log("The rows which have INCOMPLETE are - ");
console.log(r);
console.log("Total number of rows is - ");
console.log(count);
```

Comment: No it doesn't show up any information regard it. Whether it is working or not. It only shows up in console one line Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
reading?

Comment: ok, what is your expected result? do you just want to show where the "INCOMPLETE" words exist?

Answer (score 0):

### [Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6QaJ/)

The array count contains number of occurences of cells with string 'INCOMPLETE' in each row.

**Sample Markup:**

```
<table id='records'>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td><td>INCOMPLETE</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>INCOMPLETE</td><td>INCOMPLETE</td><td>INCOMPLETE</td></tr>
        <tr><td>INCOMPLETE</td><td>INCOMPLETE</td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("records");
var rows = table1.rows, rowElements, count = [];
    
for ( i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
{
    count[i] = 0;
    rowElements = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(j = 0; j < rowElements.length; j++) {
        if(rowElements[j].innerHTML == "INCOMPLETE") {
            count[i]++;
        }
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var table1 = document.getElementById("records");

var total_arr = new Array();
for ( i = 0; i< table1.rows.length; i++) 
{  
  console.log('Hi');
  console.log(length);
  console.log('bye');     
  for(j=0;j<table1.rows[i].cells.length;j++){
    if(table1.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML.trim()=='INCOMPLETE'){ 
      console.log(i+' '+j);
      console.log(total_arr);
      if(total_arr.indexOf(i)==-1) total_arr.push(i);
    }
  }
}
console.log("Total rows: "+table1.rows.length);
console.log('Total rows with incomplete: '+total_arr.length);
</script>
```

as @tun jurny kyaw mentioned you were assigning values to the cell and row during each loop so you were getting infinite loop.